# Como configurar um app para lançar na Google play e Apple Store

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic, google-play, apple

Estou desenvolvendo um App usando *Ionic/Cordova* e me veio algumas dúvidas, são elas:

1. Devo fazer algum tipo de configuração especifica no meu arquivo
   `Package.Json` para não ter problemas futuros quando for gerar uma
   atualização do mesmo na *Google Play ou Apple Store*?
2. Quando eu for lançar uma atualização devo apenas mudar a versão do
   App e subir para as lojas(*Aplle Store e Google Play*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é necessário modificar nada no `package.json`, o único arquivo que você deve modificar toda vez que for gerar uma nova versão do App é o `config.xml`, que fica na raiz do projeto. Modifique apenas o `versionCode` e `version` que o framework vai fazer o resto por você.

```
<widget id="com.ionicframework.application466003" android-versionCode="100000" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Para publicar seu App siga o tutorial da pagina do ionic framework:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Comment: Valeu @Luks Sys! Então seguindo essa lógica name, description e author do arquivo config.xml serão as tags de informação q apareceram para as pessoas q forem baixar o app correto?

Comment: Eu não sei te dizer com toda certeza mas é bem provável que não.